# Can Git be used as a database? Is there an npm package or JS lib for this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, nosql

I'm interested in using Git as a file-based NoSQL database.

Is there an npm module for this, or a JavaScript lib?

I can easily see CRUD (create read update delete) operations working fine.

Slightly worried how searching would work. If this is a bad idea let me know why please.

Comment: Asking for a lib is off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can theoretically use git as a NoSQL database, there is no underlying reason or documentation stating what git is to be explicitly used for. Though I am sure [Github](http://github.com/) will probably have some policy against.

To get to your question, you can use git quite successfully as a key-value pair store. You will obviously use the local file system to store the data then *git commit* when you are ready to commit the data to your "database".

You can create "tables" with sub-folders and the individual rows by saving .json files with your row as the file name. Writing a parser to serialize and deserialize wouldn't be so difficult. You would also be able to use the commit ID (as it is unique) to be your key for the specific row and only commit one row at a time. As they say, there are many ways to skin a cat.

As others have pointed out you can use the following [library](https://github.com/creationix/js-git). I haven't used it before, nor really looked at it in-depth but I am sure you can make it work. Otherwise, just write your own de/serializer.