# Is there a way to save a version control for text-heavy fields in relational databases?

Tags: sql-server, database, git, version-control, versioning

I am creating a project focused on creating and editing "wikis" with SQL server as DataBase, Node.js As REST API, and Angular in FrontEnd. The main idea is that these wikis are written in the Markdown format and all the content of the wiki is stored in a relational database.

The problem is that the client wants a version control associated with each time the user saves the document (something similar to what Google Drive does). Therefore, every time the content is saved, the previous content cannot be overwritten.

One of the solutions that came to my mind was to create a table that would only be in charge of saving the content that the user writes, together with the date and time when the save is made. However, the problem with this, is that if the content is too large it would be using too much unnecessary space each time the save is performed. (Assuming that the content can be exactly the same as the previous one but with one more character)

[Relational diagram for the content of the wiki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXVT1.png)

Therefore, another solution that came to my mind was to use GIT to be able to handle version control, so that every time a new wiki is created, a new branch is created with the wiki id, and a record of the document created is kept. Something similar to what is in the following post:
[Use GIT as NoSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48417866/can-git-be-used-as-a-database-is-there-an-npm-package-or-js-lib-for-this)

This solution seems to be too complicated for what I really want to achieve and also, I have no knowledge of non-relational databases and I don't know if it would be a good idea to mix these two types of DB.

So what I wanted to know is if there is any correct way to do the version control of a single field that contains a lot of information in an efficient way with relational databases, and in case it doesn't exist, I would like to know what would be the best approach to solve this problem.

Comment: "*all the content of the wiki is stored in a relational database*" Consider whether this requirement is necessary, then you can just store the text in Git. Store the commit ID for the content in the database. Similar to how one should avoid saving images in a database. Store the image on disk, only save a reference to the image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Schwern, actually, **it's not a necessary requirement**, The solution you propose can help me a lot. I'm going to try to create a proof of concept to see how it might work.  Do you know if there is a way to run git commands from Node.js?
_PS: Think about moving your comment as an answer to place it as accepted._